# Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, stdout, tee

How can I run a command-line application in the Windows command prompt and have the output both displayed and redirected to a file at the same time?

If, for example, I were to run the command `dir > test.txt`, this would redirect output to a file called `test.txt` without displaying the results.

How could I write a command to display the output **and** redirect output to a file in the Windows command prompt, similar to the `tee` command on Unix?

Comment: And please stop calling it MSDOS! The similarities between cmd.exe and that braindead command.com are minuscule, and getting smaller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I echo and send console output to a file in a bat script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script)

Comment: None of these work if one has a console application that loads a dll that outputs text. The main application text gets redirected to a file but the output from the dll does not and continues to be displayed in the console window. I have found NO way to capture the text from the dll.

Comment: one could still just pipe into a file and use tail (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command) on that file

Comment: What if i am using a command line utility and want to redirect the output to a file in the exact same format as displayed on screen i used youtube-dl to extract links and could redirect the output to a txt file , but its not formatted as you will get in the prompt , in the file its coming as single line.

Answer (score 215):

To expand on [davor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438402/148241), you can use PowerShell like this:

```
powershell "dir | tee test.txt"
```

If you're trying to redirect the output of an exe in the current directory, you need to use `.\` on the filename, eg:

```
powershell ".\something.exe | tee test.txt"
```

Comment: This is the most close answer: it works on default install, as PS is already there on most machines and, especially, servers.

Comment: This is the best answer!  Simple and works "out of the box"

Comment: It works, but the file will not contain all the output

Comment: LIKE IT :) anyhow {powershell "ping -n 10 localhost | tee test.txt"} would demonstrate better whats going on on the tee party

Comment: note that `dir` in powershell is an alias to `Get-ChildItem` which is not like cmd's internal `dir` command. You need `powershell "cmd /c dir | tee test.txt"` if you want the cmd internal version

Comment: to see all the output, don't forget to redirect STDERR to STDOUT with `2>&1`, for example `node 2>&1 | tee debug_log.txt`

Comment: But you lose the text color on console output.

Comment: Is is very useful command, we we want to have everything, we need 2>&1

Comment: Consider adding '-Append' so the log file doesn't get truncated each command start. For example `powershell "node server.js 2>&1 | tee -Append app.log"`

Comment: With `2>&1` any stderr output will cause a "NativeCommandError" to be displayed, intermixed with the actual output. To prevent that use `powershell ".\something.exe 2>&1 | foreach {\"$_\"} | tee test.txt"`. This converts any error records to plain text before sending it to `tee`.

Comment: This is not writing to a file in windows 10

Comment: @alexei In my experience: `powershell "ping -n 10 localhost | tee test.txt"` *does* return output in real time. But `powershell "&\"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe\" -Scan -ScanType 3 -File "%CD%" -DisableRemediation | tee -FilePath antivirusLog.txt"` doesn't - it only returns the output after finishing the scan. (What gives? Maybe the `tee` cmdlet somehow caches the output instead of immediately passing it on?)

Comment: @MikeRosoft My comment was incorrect (deleted), my experiment was flawed. If source process flushes its output stream, Tee does get the data chunk immediately. (I tried flushing early on, but had an unrelated flaw that made it look as if flushing did not help.) Perhaps the process in your example doesn't flush? e.g. in Python: print("foo", flush=True).

Comment: You can also wrap this up in a one-line batch file, eg tee.bat: `@powershell -command "$Input | tee '%~f1'"` and add it to your path.  Then you can just: `do_the_thing.exe | tee ".\Zhu Li.log"`

Answer (score 148):

I was able to find a solution/workaround of redirecting output to a file **and then** to the console:

```
dir > a.txt | type a.txt
```

where **dir** is the command which output needs to be redirected, **a.txt** a file where to store output.

Comment: This satisfies the answer, but outputs the data after the dir command has completed rather than as the data is produced.

Comment: it will work, but you will get stuck if the command wait a input from stdin.

Comment: I like this simple answer!  I found that an `&` instead of a `|` is needed for the output of some commands, like `ping` or `7z.exe`

Comment: Not working for interactive commands instead of `dir`. Example: `chkdsk /f c: > c:\Temp.txt | c:\Temp.txt` . The system report file is locked by another process.

Comment: This command does not seem to handle output to stderr. Stderr seems to be printed to the console but is not saved in the file.

Comment: @lii re: `handle output to stderr` - Add the `2>&1` redirection so it is like this: `dir 2>&1 > a.txt & type a.txt` and you _should_ have stderr mixed in with stdout.

Comment: I agree with @WesLarson, `&` or `&&` is better than a pipe `|`... the pipe may not print the entire redirect for long outputs because it doesn't wait for completion, `&` does wait for completion and is required for delayed output.

Comment: yeah but i got ugly whitespace, any direction?

Comment: @JesseChisholm, `dir 2>&1 > a.txt & type a.txt` both redirects the results to a log file and shows them on the screen. But the displaying of result to screen is delayed until the command is done. Is there a way so that the displaying of result to screen happens at the same time it is written to the log file?

Comment: @LHC -- Only by using a utility like `tee`. There are various packages to get unlx-like (or linux-like) utilities that run on windows.  There is no native Windows way.

Comment: did not work for me:                                                                                   
C:\Data>echo 12 > log.html | type log.html
File not found error (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.)

Comment: Just to add another caveat to this solution: If you rely on the errorlevel (aka return code) of the command, the chain to type will overwrite it (e.g. if the first command exits with non-zero, this chain will still return 0 if the file exists)

Answer (score 109):

There's a Win32 port of the Unix `tee` command, that does exactly that. See http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ or http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The link points to a Windows implementation of the Unix command tee, so it does work on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, voting up the answer and the comment. I'd actually prefer CygWin since it has everything but some people prefer non-DLL tools that they can pick and choose.

Comment: Lots of Unix utilities are also ported by GnuWin32 project, see http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: UnxUtils was last updated in 2003; GnuWin32 is a bit more up-to-date.

Comment: why use this when there is native support in windows as per the answer below??

Comment: @Feanor: Did you read the comment on that answer? While it works for some cases, it has it's limitation. Both answers are valid and have their uses.

Comment: When down voting please leave a comment. Thanks.

Comment: If you, like me, struggled to find GnuWin32's `tee` package, you'll find it in http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm.

Comment: More details is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file/62771772#62771772

Answer (score 62):

Check this out: [wintee](http://code.google.com/p/wintee/)

No need for cygwin.

I did encounter and report some issues though.

Also you might check [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) because it contains tee (and no need for cygwin), but beware that output EOL's are UNIX-like here.

Last, but not least, is if you have PowerShell, you could try Tee-Object. Type `get-help tee-object` in PowerShell console for more info.

Comment: Why the down vote? 95% of replies here have one thing in common: the output is redirected only after the initial command has finished: read the comments. UNIX utility `tee` outputs real time. `wtee` has the same functionality. If you don’t mind the bugs, it will do just fine.

Comment: That's the only solution working for me, not having Powershell > 4.0. Thumbs up!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.
`wtee` works on `Win 2003 Srv` at least, starts much faster than `powersell` and can be easily integrated into the building process.

Answer (score 55):

@tori3852

I found that

```
dir > a.txt | type a.txt
```

didn't work (first few lines of dir listing only - suspect some sort of process forking and the second part, the 'type' command terminated before the dire listing had completed? ),
so instead I used:

```
dir > z.txt && type z.txt
```

which did - sequential commands, one completes before the second starts.

Comment: You should use `&` instead of `&&` if you want to ensure the `type` command is executed even if `dir` command failed. This is useful when there was some form of error in your command and you still want to see the log file on the console. See [Microsoft's article on this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279253). However, this has the issue of `%errorlevel%` being set to the error level of `type` (which would be 0).

Answer (score 27):

Unfortunately there is no such thing.

Windows console applications only have a single output handle. (Well, there are two `STDOUT`, `STDERR` but it doesn't matter here) The `>` redirects the output normally written to the console handle to a file handle.

If you want to have some kind of multiplexing you have to use an external application which you can divert the output to. This application then can write to a file and to the console again.

Comment: `tee` on *nix is also a separate application, not some redirection on the shell

Answer (score 27):

A simple C# console application would do the trick:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace CopyToFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var buffer = new char[100];
            var outputs = new List<TextWriter>();

            foreach (var file in args)
                outputs.Add(new StreamWriter(file));

            outputs.Add(Console.Out);

            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = Console.In.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                outputs.ForEach(o => o.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            } while (bytesRead == buffer.Length);

            outputs.ForEach(o => o.Close());
        }
    }
}
```

To use this you just pipe the source command into the program and provide the path of any files you want to duplicate the output to.  For example:

```
dir | CopyToFiles files1.txt files2.txt
```

Will display the results of dir as well as store the results in both files1.txt and files2.txt.

Note that there isn't much (anything!) in the way of error handling above, and supporting multiple files may not actually be required.

Comment: Hmm, download tee/cygwin for nothing or buy MSVS with my hard-earned cash for a piddly little program like that? That's a tough one :-)

Comment: You don't need visual studio to compile that, the commandline tools are actually free. just google ".net sdk download" for the link (the direct link seems to change around but google always seems to work).

Comment: Visual Studio Express is free as well, but I would still just use tee for this.

Comment: Home-made tee implementation? And have to learn C#? Use tee.. really.

Comment: cygwin is a pain to install. Upvote to you because this is what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't think this outputs to the console and the files at the same time does it?

Comment: mjaggard: god point. It could easily be modified to do it though by adding an additional output that WAS the console.out stream.

Comment: @paxdiablo Just make a Compilar.bat with this line: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe %1 and then save his code to CopyToFiles.cs and drag it onto the bat file to create the executable.

Comment: You can install cygwin with one line like so:  
`(setlocal enableDelayedExpansion&set packs=C:\prg\sysdata\cygpackages&mkdir !packs!&cd !packs!&echo !packs!&curl -O "https://cygwin.org/setup-x86_64.exe"&!packs!\setup-x86_64.exe --no-admin -q -n -N -d -R c:\prg\cygwin64 -l !packs!\cygwin64localpacks -s https://cygwin.mirror.constant.com -P wget)`.    
    You can call a program like  `c:\prg\cygwin64\bin\tee.exe` 
or 
You can add cygwin to the local user's path with: 
`rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`.  Add this path:  `c:\prg\cygwin64\bin`

Answer (score 22):

This works, though it's a bit ugly:

```
dir >_ && type _ && type _ > a.txt
```

It's a little more flexible than some of the other solutions, in that it works statement-by-statement so you can use it to append as well.  I use this quite a bit in batch files to log and display messages:

```
ECHO Print line to screen and log to file.  >_ && type _ && type _ >> logfile.txt
```

Yes, you could just repeat the ECHO statement (once for the screen and the second time redirecting to the logfile), but that looks just as bad and is a bit of a maintenance issue.  At least this way you don't have to make changes to messages in two places.

Note that _ is just a short filename, so you'll need to make sure to delete it at the end of your batch file (if you're using a batch file).

Comment: That's only useful if you want to display the contents AFTER your process has run.  And that isn't a hard problem to solve.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this addresses a slightly different problem from what the original poster was asking.

Comment: +1 This is how I've always done it.  I believe this is the correct answer to the original question and should be marked as so.  The trick, as @MTS hints at, is that you actually write to two files: one that gets created per each command/line (hence a single ">" that overwrites each time), and then you type that line to the screen (type _), and finally, you type it again and redirect its output, all the long APPENDING, to your log file with ">>".  This is how I've done it for years, though I love the simple "_" temp file.  I've always done "tmp.txt" or soemthing.  Yeah, delete it afterwards.

Comment: This is a good approach but I had problems with some errors not getting captured. Putting the `type` commands on separate lines (in a subroutine) fixed that though.

Comment: Just what I needed for my application.

Answer (score 21):

I’d like to expand a bit on Saxon Druce’s [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20854632/3477385).

As stated, you can redirect the output of an executable in the current directory like so:

```
powershell ".\something.exe | tee test.txt"
```

However, this only logs `stdout` to `test.txt`. It doesn’t also log `stderr`.

The obvious solution would be to use something like this:

```
powershell ".\something.exe 2>&1 | tee test.txt"
```

However, this won’t work for all `something.exe`s. Some `something.exe`s will interpret the `2>&1` as an argument and fail. The correct solution is to instead only have apostrophes around the `something.exe` and its switches and arguments, like so:

```
powershell ".\something.exe --switch1 --switch2 … arg1 arg2 …" 2^>^&1 ^| tee test.txt
```

Notice though, that in this case you have to escape the special cmd-shell characters ">&|" with a "^" each so they only get interpreted by powershell.

Comment: I tried this when building pyqt5.7 on windows 10, it's quite sluggish, console output is not realtime, maybe it's buffered? the log file looks correct though

Comment: All of that is completely wrong. It doesn't work at all for me. The last command gives `'tee' is not recognized as an internal or external command` for obvious reasons. With `2>&1` inside cmd line any output to stderr causes errors from powershell.

Comment: Could be a reference to the PowerShell Tee-Object cmdlet - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177014.aspx

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970939/right-usage-of-21-tee-or-tee-with-powershell so it's not all red

Comment: @PavelP I guess, your issue was with the last example!? The command was missing the necessary escaping of special characters exposed to cmd.  It has now been edited and should work that way!

Answer (score 18):

mtee is a small utility which works very well for this purpose.  It's free, source is open, and it Just Works.

You can find it at  http://www.commandline.co.uk.

Used in a batch file to display output AND create a log file simultaneously, the syntax looks like this:

```
    someprocess | mtee /+ mylogfile.txt
```

Where /+ means to append output.

This assumes that you have copied mtee into a folder which is in the PATH, of course.

Comment: This seems to wait until the output is complete also before outputting to either the file or console.

Comment: Beware of issues: https://github.com/ritchielawrence/mtee/issues/4

Answer (score 10):

I agree with Brian Rasmussen, the unxutils port is the easiest way to do this. In the [Batch Files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php) section of his [Scripting Pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/) Rob van der Woude provides a wealth of information on the use MS-DOS and CMD commands. I thought he might have a native solution to your problem and after digging around there I found [TEE.BAT](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/tee.php#TeeNT), which appears to be just that, an MS-DOS batch language implementation of tee. It is a pretty complex-looking batch file and my inclination would still be to use the unxutils port.

Comment: That tee.bat thing looks nice.  Hope OP checks this out.

Comment: Note that using TEE.BAT will output after the command has completed, just like the "dir > a.txt | type a.txt" example posted nearby.

Answer (score 10):

If you have cygwin in your windows environment path you can use:

```
 dir > a.txt | tail -f a.txt
```

Comment: If you're going to use Cygwin, it comes with tee.

Comment: Cygwin tee doesn't seem to work on the dos prompt the way it works in bash. This is a nice workaround. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

`dir 1>a.txt 2>&1 | type a.txt`

This will help to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried using this to launch the JBoss run.bat and it chokes during startup and the server freezes.  There are problems with this method...

Comment: @raja ashok, doesn't work for me. I have tried **python.exe 1>file.txt 2>&1 | type file.txt**

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a very old topic, but in previous answers there is not a full implementation of a real time Tee written in Batch. My solution below is a Batch-JScript hybrid script that use the JScript section just to get the output from the piped command, but the processing of the data is done in the Batch section. This approach have the advantage that any Batch programmer may modify this program to fit specific needs. This program also correctly process the output of CLS command produced by other Batch files, that is, it clear the screen when CLS command output is detected.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem APATee.bat: Asynchronous (real time) Tee program, Batch-JScript hybrid version
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem The advantage of this program is that the data management is written in Batch code,
rem so any Batch programmer may modify it to fit their own needs.
rem As an example of this feature, CLS command is correctly managed

if "%~1" equ "" (
   echo Duplicate the Stdout output of a command in the screen and a disk file
   echo/
   echo anyCommand ^| APATee teeFile.txt [/A]
   echo/
   echo If /A switch is given, anyCommand output is *appended* to teeFile.txt
   goto :EOF
)

if "%2" equ ":TeeProcess" goto TeeProcess

rem Get the output of CLS command
for /F %%a in ('cls') do set "cls=%%a"

rem If /A switch is not provided, delete the file that receives Tee output
if /I "%~2" neq "/A" if exist %1 del %1

rem Create the semaphore-signal file and start the asynchronous Tee process
echo X > Flag.out
if exist Flag.in del Flag.in
Cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" | "%~F0" %1 :TeeProcess
del Flag.out
goto :EOF

:TeeProcess
   rem Wait for "Data Available" signal
   if not exist Flag.in goto TeeProcess
   rem Read the line sent by JScript section
   set line=
   set /P line=
   rem Set "Data Read" acknowledgement
   ren Flag.in Flag.out
   rem Check for the standard "End Of piped File" mark
   if "!line!" equ ":_EOF_:" exit /B
   rem Correctly manage CLS command
   if "!line:~0,1!" equ "!cls!" (
      cls
      set "line=!line:~1!"
   )
   rem Duplicate the line in Stdout and the Tee output file
   echo(!line!
   echo(!line!>> %1
goto TeeProcess


@end


// JScript section

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
// Process all lines of Stdin
while ( ! WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   // Read the next line from Stdin
   var line = WScript.Stdin.ReadLine();
   // Wait for "Data Read" acknowledgement
   while ( ! fso.FileExists("Flag.out") ) {
      WScript.Sleep(10);
   }
   // Send the line to Batch section
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line);
   // Set "Data Available" signal
   fso.MoveFile("Flag.out", "Flag.in");
}
// Wait for last "Data Read" acknowledgement
while ( ! fso.FileExists("Flag.out") ) {
      WScript.Sleep(10);
}
// Send the standard "End Of piped File" mark
WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(":_EOF_:");
fso.MoveFile("Flag.out", "Flag.in");
```

Comment: Any way this could capture the stderr output? I have an annoying exe that outputs everything on the standard error stream (i.e. in order to output to a file normally you would do `file.exe 2>output.txt`

Comment: I figured it out. You can do it using `file.exe 2>&1|tee.bat` as found here: https://superuser.com/questions/452763/how-to-pipeline-stderr-in-cmd-exe

Answer (score 6):

I was also looking for the same solution, after a little try, I was successfully able to achieve that in Command Prompt. Here is my solution :

```
@Echo off
for /f "Delims=" %%a IN (xyz.bat) do (
%%a > _ && type _ && type _ >> log.txt
)
@Echo on
```

It even captures any PAUSE command as well.

Comment: That feels like a hack. It still can't stream massive output from third party applications that you invoke in your batch file. I'm still impressed this is even possible.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do what you need?

```
%DATE%_%TIME% > c:\a.txt & type c:\a.txt
ipconfig >> c:\a.txt & type c:\a.txt
ping localhost >> c:\a.txt & type c:\a.txt
pause
```

Comment: Almost, but it does not display simultaneously - if you have a long running task, you will get no results for long time.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample of what I've used based on one of the other answers

```
@echo off
REM SOME CODE
set __ERROR_LOG=c:\errors.txt
REM set __IPADDRESS=x.x.x.x

REM Test a variable
if not defined __IPADDRESS (
     REM Call function with some data and terminate
     call :TEE %DATE%,%TIME%,IP ADDRESS IS NOT DEFINED
     goto :EOF
)

REM If test happens to be successful, TEE out a message and end script.
call :TEE Script Ended Successful
goto :EOF


REM THE TEE FUNCTION
:TEE
for /f "tokens=*" %%Z in ("%*") do (
     >  CON ECHO.%%Z
     >> "%__ERROR_LOG%" ECHO.%%Z
     goto :EOF
)
```

Answer (score 4):

send output to console, append to console log, delete output from current command

```
dir  >> usb-create.1 && type usb-create.1 >> usb-create.log | type usb-create.1 && del usb-create.1
```

Comment: care to explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

This is not another answer, but more an overview and clarification to the already existed answers like
[Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file/796492#796492)
and others

I've found for myself that there is a set of issues what makes a set of tee implementations are not reliable in the Windows (`Windows 7` in mine case).

I need to use specifically a tee implementation because have already uses a batch script with self redirection:

```
@echo off

setlocal


... some conditions here ..

rem the redirection
"%COMSPEC%" /C call %0 %* 2>&1 | "<path_to_tee_utililty>" ".log\<log_file_name_with_date_and_time>.%~nx0.log"
exit /b

:IMPL
... here the rest of script ...
```

The script and calls to some utilities inside the script can break the output if used together with a tee utility.

---

1. *The gnuwin32 implementation*:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

**Pros**:

- Correctly handles standard output together with a console progress bar, where the `\r` character is heavily used.

**Cons**:

- Makes console progress bars to draw only in a log file, but it has not duplicated or visible in the console window.
- Throws multiple error messages `Cwrite error: No such file or directory` because seems the cmd interpreter closes the pipe/stdout too early and can not self close after that (spamming until termination).
- Does not duplicate/print the output from the `pause` command (`Press any key to continue...`) in the console window.

---

2. *The wintee implementation*:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/wintee/

https://github.com/rbuhl/wintee

**Pros**:

- Shows a console progress bar both in the console window and in a log file (multiple prints).
- Does duplicate/print the output from the `pause` command (`Press any key to continue...`) in the console window.

**Cons**:

- Incorrectly handles the `\r` character, output is mixed and messed (https://code.google.com/archive/p/wintee/issues/7 ).
- Having other issues: https://code.google.com/archive/p/wintee/issues

---

3. *The UnxUtils* implementation:

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/

**Pros**

- Shows a console progress bar both in the console window and in a log file (multiple prints).
- Correctly handles the `\r` character.
- Does duplicate/print the output from the `pause` command (`Press any key to continue...`) in the console window.

**Cons**

*Not yet found*

---

4. The *ss64.net* implementation:

http://ss64.net/westlake/nt

http://ss64.net/westlake/nt/tee.zip

**Pros**:

- Shows a console progress bar both in the console window and in a log file (multiple prints).

**Cons**:

- Incorrectly handles the `\r` character, output is mixed and messed
- For some reason does duplicate/print the output from the `pause` command (`Press any key to continue...`) in the console window AFTER a key press.

---

5. The *ritchielawrence mtee* implementation:

https://ritchielawrence.github.io/mtee

https://github.com/ritchielawrence/mtee

**Pros**

- Shows a console progress bar both in the console window and in a log file (multiple prints).
- Correctly handles the `\r` character.
- Does duplicate/print the output from the `pause` command (`Press any key to continue...`) in the console window.
- The error code retain feature w/o a need to use workaround with the `doskey` (`/E` flag, [Windows command interpreter: how to obtain exit code of first piped command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170753/windows-command-interpreter-how-to-obtain-exit-code-of-first-piped-command) )

**Cons**

- Does not support forward slash characters in the path to a log file (https://github.com/ritchielawrence/mtee/issues/6 )
- Has a race condition issue, when can not extract a pipe process exit code because it has closed before it's access (https://github.com/ritchielawrence/mtee/issues/4 )

---

So, if you are choosing the tee utility implementation between the above, then a better choice is the `UnxUtils` or `mtee`.

---

If you are searching for a better implementation with more features and less issues, then you can use `callf` utility:
https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Utilities/src/callf/help.tpl

You can run instead of:

```
call test.bat | mtee /E 1.log
```

This:

```
callf.exe /ret-child-exit /tee-stdout 1.log /tee-stdout-dup 1 "" "cmd.exe /c call test.bat"
```

It is better because it can pipe `stdout` separately from `stderr` and you can even pipe between processes with Administrator privileges isolation using named pipes.

Comment: unixutils package link does not working, update package does not include tee utility. There are another tee implementations http://ss64.net/westlake/nt/ and https://www.robvanderwoude.com/unixports.php

Comment: @user2956477 I've added another link. I think the update package should not have all set of utilities, only those the author wants to update.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation on a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333976/4459336) by MTS, however it adds some functionality that might be useful to others.  Here is the method that I used:

- A command is set as a variable, that can be used later throughout the code, to output to the command window and append to a log file, using `set _Temp_Msg_Cmd=`

  - the command has escaped [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) using the caret `^` character so that the commands are not evaluated initially
- A temporary file is created with a filename similar to the batch file being run called `%~n0_temp.txt` that uses [command line parameter extension syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) `%~n0` to get the name of the batch file.
- The output is appended to a separate log file `%~n0_log.txt`

Here is the sequence of commands:

1. The output and error messages are sent to the temporary file `^> %~n0_temp.txt 2^>^&1`
2. The content of the temporary file is then both:

- appended to the logfile `^& type %~n0_temp.txt ^>^> %~n0_log.txt`
- output to the command window `^& type %~n0_temp.txt`

3. The temporary file with the message is deleted `^& del /Q /F %~n0_temp.txt`

Here is the example:

`set _Temp_Msg_Cmd= ^> %~n0_temp.txt 2^>^&1 ^& type %~n0_temp.txt ^>^> %~n0_log.txt ^& type %~n0_temp.txt ^& del /Q /F %~n0_temp.txt`

This way then the command can simply be appended after later commands in a batch file that looks a lot cleaner:

`echo test message %_Temp_Msg_Cmd%`

This can be added to the end of other commands as well.  As far as I can tell it will work when messages have multiple lines.  For example the following command outputs two lines if there is an error message:

`net use M: /D /Y %_Temp_Msg_Cmd%`

Answer (score 2):

Just like unix.

`dir | tee a.txt`

Does work On windows XP, it requires `mksnt` installed.

It displays on the prompt as well as appends to the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo on

set startDate=%date%
set startTime=%time%

set /a sth=%startTime:~0,2%
set /a stm=1%startTime:~3,2% - 100
set /a sts=1%startTime:~6,2% - 100


fullprocess.bat > C:\LOGS\%startDate%_%sth%.%stm%.%sts%.LOG | fullprocess.bat
```

---

This will create a log file with the current datetime and you can the console lines during the process

Comment: aren't you calling the same program twice with this?

Answer (score 1):

I use a batch subroutine with a "for" statement to get the command output one line at a time and both write that line to a file and output it to the console.

```
@echo off
set logfile=test.log

call :ExecuteAndTee dir C:\Program Files

Exit /B 0

:ExecuteAndTee
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Executing '%*'
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%* 2^>^&1') do (echo.%%a & echo.%%a>>%logfile%)
endlocal
Exit /B 0
```

Comment: I do the same when trying to capture output from a command (IE put it inside a for) but then I just call my standard subfunction to echo to the screen and write to the log because I use it throughout my script in replacement of using echo.  Not sure why that got a downvote from others so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on the CLI, why not use a FOR loop to "DO" whatever you want:

```
for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir') do @echo %a && echo %a >> output.txt
```

Great resource on Windows CMD for loops: https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html
The key here is setting the delimeters (delims), that would break up each line of output, to nothing. This way it won't break on the default of white-space. The %a is an arbitrary letter, but it is used in the "do" section to, well... do something with the characters that were parsed at each line. In this case we can use the ampersands (&&) to execute the 2nd echo command to create-or-append (>>) to a file of our choosing. Safer to keep this order of DO commands in case there's an issue writing the file, we'll at least get the echo to the console first. The at sign (@) in front of the first echo suppresses the console from showing the echo-command itself, and instead just displays the result of the command which is to display the characters in %a. Otherwise you'd see:

> echo Volume in drive [x] is Windows
>  Volume in drive [x] is Windows

UPDATE: /F skips blank lines and only fix is to pre-filter the output adding a character to every line (maybe with line-numbers via the command find). Solving this in CLI isn't quick or pretty. Also, I didn't include STDERR, so here's capturing errors as well:

```
for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir 2^>^&1') do @echo %a & echo %a >> output.txt
```

[Redirecting Error Messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout)

The carets (^) are there to escape the symbols after them, because the command is a string that's being interpreted, as opposed to say, entering it directly on the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to use the perl as alternative, e.g.:

`CMD1 | perl -ne "print $_; print STDERR $_;" 2> OUTPUT.TEE`

Answer (score 0):

Following helps if you want something really seen on the screen - even if the batch file was redirected to a file. The device CON maybe used also if redirected to a file

Example:

```
ECHO first line on normal stdout. maybe redirected
ECHO second line on normal stdout again. maybe redirected
ECHO third line is to ask the user. not redirected  >CON
ECHO fourth line on normal stdout again. maybe redirected
```

Also see good redirection description:  http://www.p-dd.com/chapter7-page14.html

Answer (score 0):

> How do I display and redirect output
>   to a file. Suppose if I use dos
>   command, dir > test.txt ,this command
>   will redirect output to file test.txt
>   without displaying the results. how to
>   write a command to display the output
>   and redirect output to a file using
>   DOS i.e., windows command prompt, not
>   in UNIX/LINUX.

You may find these commands in biterscripting ( http://www.biterscripting.com ) useful.

```
var str output
lf > $output
echo $output                            # Will show output on screen.
echo $output > "test.txt"               # Will write output to file test.txt.
system start "test.txt"                 # Will open file test.txt for viewing/editing.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in real time but is also kind a ugly and the performance is slow.   Not well tested either:

```
@echo off
cls
SET MYCOMMAND=dir /B
ECHO File called 'test.bat' > out.txt
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`%MYCOMMAND%`) do (
  ECHO %%I
  ECHO %%I >> out.txt
) 
pause
```

Comment: No, it's not real time, it waits until `%MYCOMMAND%` is finished and it fails in many cases. It skips empty lines, lines beginning with `;` fails with content like `<space>/<TAB>`, `ON`, `OFF` or `/?`. But the rest could sometimes work :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to tee stdout to stderr within your program:

in java:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new TeeOutputStream(System.out, System.err)));
```

Then, in your dos batchfile: `java program > log.txt`

The stdout will go to the logfile and the stderr (same data) will show on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I install perl on most of my machines so an answer using perl:  tee.pl

```
my $file = shift || "tee.dat";
open $output, ">", $file or die "unable to open $file as output: $!";
while(<STDIN>)
{
    print $_;
    print $output $_;
}
close $output;
```

dir | perl tee.pl
or 
dir | perl tee.pl dir.bat

crude and untested.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation is to split the pipe, and then re-direct the output as you like.

```
    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%P in ('findstr /n "^"') do (
      echo(%%Q
      echo(%%Q>&3
    )
    @exit/b %errorlevel%
```

Save the above to a .bat file.  It splits text output on filestream 1 to filestream 3 also, which you can redirect as needed.  In my examples below, I called the above script splitPipe.bat ...

```
    dir | splitPipe.bat  1>con  2>&1  3>my_stdout.log

    splitPipe.bat 2>nul < somefile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

1. https://cygwin.com/install
2. Click the link for "setup-x86_.exe"
3. Run the installer
4. On ~2nd page, choose a "mirror" to download from (I looked for a .edu domain)
5. I said ok to the standard options
6. Cygwin quickly finished install
7. Open cmd
8. Type `c:\cygwin64\bin\script.exe` and enter
9. Type `cmd` and enter
10. Run your program
11. Type `exit` and enter (exits Cygwin's cmd.exe)
12. Type `exit` and enter (exits Cygwin's script.exe)
13. See the screen output of your program in text file called "typescript"