# How can I print to a variable instead of a file, in Perl?

Tags: perl, printing

How can I print to a variable with Perl?

I've been working on a program for a while which logs its **iterative** progress in a highly verbose fashion...

```
print $loghandle $some_message;
```

However, I'd like to also selectively print some of the messages to a different file. Naturally, I could sprinkle the code with...

```
print $loghandle $some_message
print $otherloghandle $some_message
```

Or rewrite the whole business into a function. Blah.

What I want to do is do some magic when I open the $loghandle so that when I'm `print`'ing, I'm actually just doing a `sprintf`ish operation against a variable(call it `$current_iteration`), so that when I get down to a decision point I can do something like this...

```
print $real_log_file $current_iteration;
print $other_real_log_file $current_iteration if($condition);
```

I'm fairly sure I've seen something like this somewhere, but I have no idea where it is or where to look.

edit: File::Tee solves this problem to some extent on *nix, but I run on Windows.

Comment: Deja vu? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532544/how-can-i-send-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-log-file-and-to-the-screen-in-win32-perl/1532691#1532691

Comment: Possibly. I'm not trying to tee the actual streams really(though that doesn't matter); it's more setting a variable to act as a destination stream. I'm being lazy and not wanting to rewrite 50-odd logging messages, see. :-)

Comment: @Paul Nathan I linked to brian d foy's answer. Use Log4perl. Express your `$condition` as a logging level, define the actions. I am not adding this as an answer as I do not have time to check how it works, but I would thoroughly recommend Log4perl based on past experience.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can treat a scalar variable as a filehandle by [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)ing it:

```
open my $fh, '>', \$variable or die "Can't open variable: $!";
print $fh "Treat this filehandle like any other\n";
```

You can even map stdout or stderr to a scalar:

```
close STDOUT;
open STDOUT, '>', \$variable or die "Can't open STDOUT: $!";
```

If you want to split your output or set up a config file to do "interesting" things with your logging, you are better off with [Log4Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl/) as others have suggested.

Comment: This might also be an excellent way to use perl formats and save the generated "report" into a variable.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like [IO::Scalar](http://search.cpan.org/~dskoll/IO-stringy-2.110/lib/IO/Scalar.pm)? Lets you write to a variable with filehandle semantics.

Comment: You don't need IO::Scalar explicitly. open() by itself works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do selective logging where you can control which messages are logged and where they are logged, use [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl). That will save you a bunch of time over messing with `tie`s and other black magic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [File::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/File-Tee/lib/File/Tee.pm) to split a filehandle into multiple output streams.

```
use File::Tee;
open my $fh, '>', 'logfile.txt' or die $!;
tee( $fh, '>', 'otherlogfile.txt' ) if $condition;

print $fh $current_iteration;   # will also go to otherlogfile.txt 
                                # if $condition was true
```

Comment: I run on Windows(File::Tee doesn't). adding that to the question.

Answer (score 2):

[Perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-print-to-more-than-one-file-at-once?) recommends [Tie::FileHandle::Multiplex](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Tie::FileHandle::MultiPlex) for printing to multiple files.

The source is very simple and it should be easy to modify with a per-handle filter.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you want to [`tie`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#tie) your filehandle.

```
my $x;

# printing to $fh will update the variable $x
# when you close $fh, it will print $x to a filehandle depending
# on code in the function  Print_to_variable::CLOSE 

tie $fh, "Print_to_variable", \$x, $output_fh1, $output_fh2;
print $fh "stuff";
print $fh "more stuff";
close $fh;

sub Print_to_variable::TIEHANDLE {
    my ($class, $ref, $fh1, $fh2) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    $self->{ref} = $ref;
    $self->{output_fh1} = $fh1;
    $self->{output_fh2} = $fh2;
    bless $self, "Print_to_variable";
    $self;
}
sub Print_to_variable::PRINT {
    my ($self,@list);
    ${$self->{ref}} .= join "", @list;
}
sub Print_to_variable::CLOSE {
    my $self = shift;
    my $text = ${$self->{ref}};
    if ( &myCondition1($text) ) {    # ... how you decide where to print 
        print {$self->{output_fh1}} $text;
    } else {
        print {$self->{output_fh1}} $text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think so, but I have the dumb today and don't see how tie actually works here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *tremendous* hack, and I think mobrule's solution or(esp) Sinan's solution of Log4Perl are the way to go when I have time.

But, this is what I'm using, as a completion thing:

```
sub print_to_var($$) {
   my($rx_var, $scalar) = @_;
   $$rx_var .= $scalar;
}


print_to_var \$logvar, $message;

#...later on...
print $somefile $logvar;
```

Edit:

Since this is community wiki, it's worth nothing that Perl aliases arguments to functions.  That means you can just write this:

```
sub print_to_var($$) {
   $_[0] .= $_[1];
}
```

And then say:

```
my $foo = "OH HAI. ";
print_to_var $foo, "I ARE HELO KITTIE.";
say $foo; # OH HAI.  I ARE HELO KITTIE.
```

This is not a particularly tremendous hack, although `print_to_var` is a lot more typing than `.` is.

And here is the HELO KITTIE:

[helo kittie http://blogs.philadelphiaweekly.com/style/files/2008/11/hello-kitty-color.gif](http://blogs.philadelphiaweekly.com/style/files/2008/11/hello-kitty-color.gif)

Comment: I am amused! And I wasn't sure about the aliasing/referencing args to functions. Thank you!