# How can I redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a log file in Perl?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I send STDOUT and STDERR to a log file and also to the screen in Win32 Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532544/can-i-send-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-log-file-and-also-to-the-screen-in-win32-perl)

I would to to redirect STDOUT, STDERR to *temp_log* and then to *logfile.txt* after the process is complete. The process runs for complete 20 minutes thus I would like to flock the *temp_log* in the time process runs.

Comment: What is your question?  What part do you need help with?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 19):

`STDOUT` and `STDERR` are just filehandles that are initialized to your program's standard output and error, but they can be reassigned at any time for any reason. For this purpose, you will want to save the original settings so you can restore them.

```
sub process_that_writes_to_temp_log {

    # save original settings. You could also use lexical typeglobs.
    *OLD_STDOUT = *STDOUT;
    *OLD_STDERR = *STDERR;

    # reassign STDOUT, STDERR
    open my $log_fh, '>>', '/logdirectory/the-log-file';
    *STDOUT = $log_fh;
    *STDERR = $log_fh;

    # ... 
    # run some other code. STDOUT/STDERR are now redirected to log file
    # ...

    # done, restore STDOUT/STDERR
    *STDOUT = *OLD_STDOUT;
    *STDERR = *OLD_STDERR;
}
```

---

Depending on how your program is laid out, saving and restoring the old STDOUT/STDERR settings can be done automatically using `local`.

```
sub routine_that_writes_to_log {
    open my $log_fh, '>>', 'log-file';
    local *STDOUT = $log_fh;
    local *STDERR = $log_fh;

    # now STDOUT,STDERR write to log file until this subroutine ends.
    # ...

}
```

Comment: `local` can be used within any block. It does not have to be a subroutine.

Comment: it doesn't work on linux for command called by system/exec function.

Comment: `system` always works with file descriptors 0, 1, and 2. If you are careful about how you reinitialize `STDOUT` and `STDERR`, you can get your new standard filehandles to work with `system`.  `exec` replaces your Perl program with another program, which will make you lose your changes to `STDOUT`/`STDERR`.

Answer (score 4):

The redirection part of your question is already answered in [Can I send STDOUT and STDERR to a log file and also to the screen in Win32 Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532544/can-i-send-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-log-file-and-also-to-the-screen-in-win32-perl). Even though it says "Win32", the answers are for portable Perl.

The other part, the temporary file, is a bit more tricky until you've been burned by it at least once.

- Name the temporary file with something that should be unique during its run. Including the PID or the program start time. You can do that on your own with something like `$filename.$$`, but you can also use [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/File-Temp).
- If you want to then append the temporary log to an existing log, you probably want to make another temp file to get the entire result. Once you have the entire thing stitched together, move it into place. That way you don't have competing processes changing the same file as they all try to append their temp logs to the main one.
- Even better, use something like [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl) since it handles all the details for you.