# Redirecting STDERR to select()ed STDOUT

Tags: perl, io-redirection

How do I redirect STDERR to the same process file handle as the one I `select()`ed STDOUT to?<sup>[1]</sup>

1. This successfully redirects STDERR to STDOUT (both lines getting printed to STDOUT):

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   open( STDERR, '>&', STDOUT );

   print "Output to STDOUT\n";
   print STDERR "Output to STDERR (redirected to STDOUT)\n";
   ```
2. This successfully pipes STDOUT to a pager (`less` in this case), while STDERR still gets written directly to the terminal. (You see STDOUT first, paged, and once you exit the pager, you see the STDERR line.)

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   open( my $pager, '|-', 'less' );
   select( $pager );

   print "Output to STDOUT (redirected to 'less')\n";
   print STDERR "Output to STDERR\n";
   ```

I would like to combine the two -- have STDERR piped to the same pager as STDOUT.

3. This does not work, I get the same results as in 2). (Funnily enough, if I pipe the script output to `less` *again* -- as in `./testme.pl | less` -- the outputs *are* combined on STDOUT. But STDERR is *not* put through the pager process opened by the script itself.)

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   open( my $pager, '|-', 'less' );
   select( $pager );

   open( STDERR, '>&', STDOUT );

   print "Output to STDOUT\n";
   print STDERR "Output to STDERR (gets redirected to STDOUT but not to 'less')\n";
   ```
4. This does not work, STDERR output vanishes completely:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   open( my $pager, '|-', 'less' );
   select( $pager );

   open( STDERR, '>', $pager );

   print "Output to STDOUT\n";
   print STDERR "Output to STDERR (but does not show up anywhere)\n";
   ```

How do I redirect STDERR to the same process file handle as the one I `select()`ed STDOUT to?<sup>[1]</sup>

---

[1]: In the actual program, I am checking that STDOUT / STDERR are not redirected by the caller already. I left those checks out of the examples for brevity.

Should `select()` be the problem here, I'd be happy with achieving the same effect -- STDOUT and STDERR piped to the same pager process -- without `select()`.

Target platforms include Git Bash for Windows, which *severely* restricts the availability of additional modules. An ideal answer would work without `use`ing e.g. `IPC::Open`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3822787/2173773

Comment: Close. `open( STDERR, '>&', $pager );`

Comment: @ikegami: No, that does not work either -- the STDERR line gets not printed at all, neither to the pager process nor the terminal directly.

Comment: [It does work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vArG.png) Note the use of `>&` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I redirect STDERR to the same process file handle as the one I select()ed STDOUT to?

The following works for me:

```
use v5.38;
my $pid = open( my $pager, '|-', 'less' ) or die "Can't start less: $!";
{
    local *STDOUT = $pager;
    local *STDERR = $pager;
    #select( $pager );

    print "Output to STDOUT\n";
    print STDERR "Output to STDERR\n";
}
close $pager;
```

### Comments to your code

- Case #3: `open( STDERR, '>&', STDOUT );` this duplicates STDOUT into STDERR, so it could have worked but for some reason it does not work together with `select`
- Case #4: `open( STDOUT, '>', $pager );` This opens `STDOUT` in write mode to a file name given by `$pager`. So this does not duplicate any descriptor

Comment: Sorry, a couple of (s/STDOUT/STDERR/) typo's in there. Fixed them in the question. (#1 / #4)

Comment: Works quite nicely for me. Any particular reason for the `use v5.38;`? My script is working from `v5.20` upward, and your construct seems to work just as well for that version too...

Comment: Re "*for some reason it does not work together with select*", Cause `select` doesn't change `STDOUT`. (It changes the default handle for print/printf/say.) You need `'>&', select()` which is equivalent to `'>&', $pager`

Comment: @DevSolar, Re "*Any particular reason for the `use v5.38;`?*", This code only requires 5.6. `use v5.38;` provides `use strict; use warnings;`, though.