# How to log maven output to a file and without hiding console?

Tags: logging, maven

I want to save maven output to a file, but without loosing the output to console. Usage of `tee` is not an option because I run under Windows and also I do not want to add a binary tee.exe to the source tree.

Comment: There is really nothing maven-specific about this. I'd suggest asking on SuperUser.com if there is a way to redirect cmd output to both a file and the console.

Comment: This is *specific* to maven and it looks that maven does not support this yet, this being really ugly for a build system.

Comment: According to @Sean comment, here are possible workarounds [How to redirect output to a text file and the console (cmd) window at the same time?](http://superuser.com/a/111854/24948) or [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/796492/251745)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using linux. you can use the bellow command.
`mvn install -X | tee log.txt`

Comment: I meant it doesn't print to the console. The log.txt is fine

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat I would expect by passing the command you've told maven (mvn) to save the logs to the file versus the default location (which on my system is 'System.out').  This is why you don't get the console output.  Just look at the log files when saving to file.  Side note - default logging location can be changed if needed via the ${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties file.  Here is a link if you need it: https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

Comment: @ZackJannsen not true. Other commands work fine. But thanks for the reply

Comment: What is `-X` for?

Comment: -X is for debug mode log

Comment: tee command is available for Windows too. It is inside Cygwin package. Maybe manual selection of tee is needed.

Answer (score 7):

Maven 3 command output can be redirected now. See the below command on windows:

```
mvn -X install  > test.log
```

This will redirect the command output to test.log file ,located in the current directory.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem of dumping it to the console simultaneous which is why he wants to use tee.

Comment: This is only writing to log file, nothing appear in the console

Answer (score 3):

As of today, maven2 does not supports this.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said you're on windows.  In powershell there is the `Tee-Object`.  I run maven as such: (note that in powershell you'll need to enclose the whole `-Dexec.args` in quotes).

```
mvn exec:java "-Dexec.mainClass=com.proj.main" "-Dexec.args=arg0 arg1" | Tee-Object -FilePath output.log
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for Windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

Use :

> file-name

at the end of your mvn command to send output to a file then use something like wintail to tail the file.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Powercmd](http://www.powercmd.com/).
It works as like normal command prompt plus some additional features like automatically log everything on screen, multiple windows, shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

use a tail command
***tail -f log_file_name*** in another console.