# How to run a sql script file using sqlcmd and output to both shell and file

Tags: logging, sqlcmd

I'm trying to run a sql script from a file using `sqlcmd`, using the following command:

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -d <database> -i <input file> -o <output file> 
      -U <user> -P <password>
```

I run my sql file and output to a log file.

The problem is this change the output of `sqlcmd` to the file.. and i want to get the output also to the shell.

Comment: did you found answer for this? please if you have it, answer here, and answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319025/sqlcmd-with-output-file-and-screen-output so ill vote up your answer if it works. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Leandro sorry didnt found an answer yet....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Noam,

There's a standard program in UNIX world that reads from *stdin* and writes to *stdout* **and** to a specified file: the [tee](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html) command. The following example lists the current directory to *stdout* and to "myfile":

```
$ ls | tee "myfile"
```

There are some open-source ports for windows, like [wintee](https://code.google.com/p/wintee/), and it's even trivial to make  your own implementation (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file)), but PowerShell actually has already this utility built-in: the [Tee-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx).The following example is analogous the previous, in PowerShell:

```
PS [c:\tmp]
> dir | tee myDirContents.txt
```

Hence, the following command will execute *myscript.sql* into *myserver,* using current windows credentials and its result will be output either to the console **and** to "result.txt":

```
PS [c:\tmp]
> sqlcmd -i mysrcipt.sql -S myserver -E | tee "result.txt"
```

Answer (score 4):

@Noam, albeit I couldn't find a way of duplicating the STDOUT handler, one solution that maybe solve you problem is to execute the sql script into the output file (i.e. `result.txt`) and then use `type result.txt` to print it into STDOUT.

```
c:>sqlcmd -i mysrcipt.sql -o result.txt -S myserver -E
c:>type result.txt
```

If you really need to duplicate the handler (maybe the command takes lots of time and you don't want to wait until it finishes before getting the first rows), you can make a simple program to copy the inputs from STDIN into STDOUT and also into a file. Then you could rewrite the command as:

```
c:>sqlcmd -i mysrcipt.sql -S myserver -E > duplicate.exe "result.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used for connection that require authentication

```
sqlcmd -S "server_name" -d "database_name" -i "input_file" -o "output_file" -U "user_name" -P "password"
```

Comment: -U & -P is for server or database?