# sqlcmd with output file and screen output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, command-line, sqlcmd

I do some command line batch (.bat) with sqlcmd as this way:

```
sqlcmd -i Scripts\STEP01.sql -o PROCESS.log -S MYSERVER -E -d MYDATABASE
```

and i need an output file (it's works currently) and also the output trought the screen to do something like:

```
@echo off
echo The result of the query was:
    sqlcmd -i Scripts\STEP01.sql -o PROCESS.log -S MYSERVER -E -d MYDATABASE
pause
CHOICE /C:YN /M "Is the result accord?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO ENDWITHERROR
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO STEP2
```

**Note**:

- Yes, the script works suscefull, it's not an issue question.
- And yes, I've a "print "something" on my sql. The log file gets the output.

Thanks a lot!

Similar question without answer:
[How to run a sql script file using sqlcmd and output to both shell and file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165319/how-to-run-a-sql-script-file-using-sqlcmd-and-output-to-both-shell-and-file)

Comment: If the log isn't too big, you could always add a TYPE PROCESS.LOG to the BAT file before the Pause.   Don't know if this will help and don't know of any way to get both file and screen output...

Comment: watch out for buffering http://stackoverflow.com/q/306945/10245

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also couldn't find a better way then @Sparky proposed. The following code adds his suggestion:

```
@echo off

:: this will execute the script into PROCESS.log
sqlcmd -i Scripts\STEP01.sql -o PROCESS.log -S MYSERVER -E -d MYDATABASE

:: this present the contents of PROCESS.log to the screen
echo The result of the query was:
type PROCESS.log

pause
CHOICE /C:YN /M "Is the result accord?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO ENDWITHERROR
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO STEP2
```

Comment: You can get more information about command redirection at this links [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc772622(v=ws.10).aspx), [link](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can use powershell instead and use the following:

```
sqlcmd -i Scripts\STEP01.sql  -S SERVER -E -d MYDB | Tee-Object -file "PROCESS.log"
```

More info from [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177014.aspx)