# How to get SqlCommand execution Result to log file ?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlcommand

I am executing query from the command prompt with following command :

```
sqlcmd -U sa -P pal#143 -S .\SQLEXPRESS -i Employee.sql -o Employee.log
```

How can I get the result of execution to log file ?

I am not getting anything in the log file.

thanks

Comment: Did you try adding the -f switch and did you check the current directory for the file to be created?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqlcmd with output file and screen output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319025/sqlcmd-with-output-file-and-screen-output)