# Logging Output of Console Application to a text file and Console Window at the same time

Tags: c#, sql, text, command-line, console-application

the following command can be used to log console application output to a text file:

```
    c:\>test.exe > output.txt
```

Is there a way to do this and display the output in a console window at the same time?

Comment: Create a program that logs to console and passes the data on :) - which then will be written to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command in this case as a workaround. This will save the output to file and then prints the file.

```
c:\>test.exe > output.txt && type output.txt
```

Comment: This works, however, is there a method which allows viewing the task running in the console output window?

Comment: There is no such option as far as I know. You can refer this thread to find any of them helps you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file

Comment: You are correct. There is no option in the console application.