# Batch script: save stdout and have the output in the console too

Tags: batch-file, console-application, stdout

By default the output of commandline applications is presented in console window and I know that using `>` or `>>` we can re-wrire/append the stdout to an external file but what if the commandline application doesn't have internal logging facility to save the output. I want the stdout to be both in the console and be saved in an external file. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/796476/5047996)

Comment: See also this post on SuperUser: [Windows: Command line redirection to text file while also seeing output](http://superuser.com/q/278115/489381)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@echo off
echo hello > log.txt & type log.txt
pause
```

But using this you can only have one command-output in the log-file at once. You could try it with `>>` but that way you get the outputs of all commands every time you use this.