# Redirect C file output to a text file

Tags: redirect, cmd, text-files

I need to redirect my **C** program output to a text file with the command line.
I need a command that automatically puts a **C** program output to a text file, and a command that takes the input to a **C** program from a text file.
Can someone help please?

Comment: look up "input redirection" and "output redirection", that is all you need to know.

Comment: You should be using the redirection operators, `<` and `>`, to provide inputs and capture outputs, respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file)

Comment: This is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need "input and output redirection".

Let's say you have a code that expects some output from user (you have `fgets()`in your code - just an example), you want program to read from file, instead of waiting for user input on cmd...

you would call it: `program.exe < input.txt`

Similarly, for output, you want `printf()` to write to file, instead of command prompt, you would do
`program.exe > output.txt`

To combine both in one line
`program.exe < input.txt > output.txt`