# How to both show the log on the console and save an external log for a crawl?

Tags: scrapy

Just like the title. I use -s LOG_FILE=mylog.txt for saving an external log. But I would like also see the log as the spider is running. Is there a way to do that? I'm using Windows 10 and prefer an answer that works in Windows 10.

Amateur developer without computing background here so please go easy on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gnu's `tee` tool:

```
scrapy crawl myspider 2>&1 | tee crawl.log
```

`2>&1` redirect stderr to stdout - you want errors and info in the same file most likely.
`| tee crawl.log` pipes that output to `tee` which splits it to `crawl.log` file and stdout.

There's `tee` implementation for windows too:

> There's a Win32 port of the Unix tee command, that does exactly that. See http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ or http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/796492/3737009

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Windows 10! And prefer an answer for win10

Comment: @siowy there's `tee` for windows too, see my edit :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!