# Running Python on Command Prompt and Logging to a File

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, io-redirection

I made this simple `.bat` batch-file containing

```
@echo off
set log=mainLog.txt
cd /d F:/Project/Python
echo [%TIME%]starting main.py >%log%
python main.py >> %log%
```

the command prompt is successfully redirect `main.py` output to the log file, but doesn't show it on prompt screen. So I change it to:

```
python main.py 2>> %log%
```

this will show the output of `main.py` to the prompt screen but not redirecting to log file. I've already tried to use:

```
python main.py 2>> %log% 1>> %log%
```

but this give me:

> The Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process

Let's assume that my `main.py` containing:

```
for i in range(10):
    print("this is line no. {}".format(i))
```

Is there any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file)

Comment: You are essentially wanting an implementation of the `TEE` command on Unix systems. Windows does not have a native command that does that.  If you want that functionality you will have to download a third party `TEE` program that works on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **type** to call and display the file(text only) in prompt

read more how to use type - [@SS64 - Type Command](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html).

*(for example)*

This script outputs to a log but you need to call the output log to be displayed on prompt.

```
@echo off
::script file path - x:\myproject\xyz.py
::script filename if batch runs in same directory - xyz.py
set myscrpt="xyz.py"

::Log file path
set pylog="myscriptlog.log"

::Python Path
pushd C:\Python27

::script output to log
echo ----------log-start---------- >%pylog%
%myscrpt% >>%pylog%
echo ----------log-end---------- >>%pylog%
cls

::Display log output in prompt
type %pylog%
pause>nul
exit
```