# Right usage of 2>&1 | tee or | tee with powershell

Tags: powershell, logging, command-line, command-line-interface

I want to see the output of the command in the console and save it in a file so I have these two options:

When I use `command | tee output.txt` somehow it generates no output file at all but it works as usual in the console.

When I use `command 2>&1 | tee output.txt` it generates a fine output file but the text in the console appears in red.
[image]

Is there any way to either fix the first option or let the text appear as usual in the second one? I am using Windows PowerShell (Windows 10) and the Programm I am using this for is liquibase 3.5.5. just for the case that this is important.

Comment: maybe `command | out-string | tee output.txt` ?

Comment: @JacobColvin when I do this it generates an empty txt file

Comment: Your executable is writing to the error stream for some reason.  You still need `2>&1` to capture its output.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 so the `| tee` parameter generates no output file because it is an error stream?

Comment: Correct.  By default, it's looking at the success (`&1`) stream.  You'd need to do `& command 2>&1 | tee ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PowerShell, redirecting stderr lines from an external program to PowerShell's success stream via `2>&1` wraps those lines in [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances in case they are captured for further processing.

In *Windows PowerShell*, these captured instances *render like PowerShell errors*, which is why you're seeing the red output (by contrast, without the redirection, the stderr lines would be *passed through* to the console, without coloring).

A simple workaround is to convert these objects to strings explicitly, which outputs the original lines (PSv3+ syntax; built-in alias `%` for `ForEach-Object` used for brevity):

```
... 2>&1 | % ToString | Tee-Object output.txt
```

Note: This workaround is *no longer necessary* in the install-on-demand, cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition, where even captured stderr lines now consistently render just as strings.

Comment: Redirecting [all streams](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) (not just Error and Output/Success but also Warning, Verbose and Debug) is possible with `*>&1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in DOS then you can leverage powershell (from DOS) and use tee-object do more or less a tee like in Linux.

```
C:\> powershell some_command ^| tee-object -FilePath some_outputfile
```

The `^` escapes the pipe so that the pipe applies to powershell and not DOS.

Powershell and tee-object should come with Windows as standard so nothing to install!

Comment: I assume you mean [`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) aka the Command Prompt, the command shell of modern Windows versions,
 not the long-obsolete DOS and its `command.com` counterpart. Given that this question isn't about calling `Tee-Object` from _outside_ PowerShell, your answer amounts to a distraction.