# Q: How can I store/save the results of Pylint execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, automated-tests, pylint

I am using Pylint, I am new to this tool, so to count the quality of my python project (test automation). I know that if I want to test the quality of one file I have to execute the following command (for Windows10):

```
pylint name_of_file.py
```

If I want to execute the whole directory, I need to create a python file named `__init__.py` in the above directory and then to execute this command:

```
pylint name_of_the_directory
```

Also, as I mentioned above, I also use PyCharm. Through the interface of this IDE, Pylint has a button named as `Check Project` which is validating the whole project. Please take a look on the screenshot of this interface:

[image]

An output from any of the above executions, would be like this:

```
something.py:12:4: C0111: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
something.py:16:4: C0111: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
something.py:20:4: C0111: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
something.py:25:4: C0111: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
something.py:31:4: C0111: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
something.py:35:4: C0111: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
something.py:39:4: C0111: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
```

**What do I need:** I want every after new build, the Pylint results to be saved in a specific directory under a `.txt` format file, having as a name the current timestamp followed by the current's project version (stored into a property file). To me (if I am not wrong), it's like keeping the log output fo Pylint execution. How can this happen?

In case is needed:

**System information**

- Python version: 3.7
- OS: Windows 10
- IDE: PyCharm version: 2018.3.4
- Framework: BDD Behave

Comment: Do you care specifically about the Check Project button, or is some other way to run pylint and save the results ok?

Comment: "Check Project" is just another way to execute the validation of the whole project using pylint. I mentioned it because may someone know where do the results be saved after clicking on this button. I inserted as much information as I could so to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working in the Windows command line, you can [redirect output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file) to the filename you need, and then [display the contents of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file) you just wrote.

```
pylint name_of_directory > <filename> 2>&1 | type <filename>
```

You can use slices of the `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` variables to get a unique filename with the timestamp.

```
>echo %DATE%
Thu 02/21/2019
>echo %DATE:~0,1%
T
>echo %DATE:~1,2%
hu
>echo %TIME%
 7:54:17.74
```

You'll have to figure out what parts you want and slice/append them into your desired name. Just trying to concatenate %DATE% and %TIME% will give you an invalid pathname. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807168/q-how-can-i-store-save-the-results-of-pylint-execution?noredirect=1#comment96390882_54807168) discussses formatting a filename with a timestamp.

Once you have the timestamp format you want, you can save your filename to a a variable to reference it just once:

```
set FILENAME="example.txt"; pylint <name_of_directory> > %FILENAME% 2>&1 | type %FILENAME%
```

Of course, this will just save it for the current command. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt) if you want to save it globally.

I assume there's a way to get PyCharm to run this command for you, but I cannot tell you how to do that.

Comment: `set FILENAME="example.txt"; pylint bdd > %FILENAME% 2>&1 | type %FILENAME%`

Comment: Then double-check your command. The `%NAME%` syntax is how Windows gets the value of a variable, so `%example.txt%` is meaningless and should never occur.

Comment: Bah, it looks like you have to set the variable and use it in two different commands. How annoying.

Comment: Yeap that's what I can see...there must be a solution for sure. All those guys who use pylint, they take the output by copy/paste? no way... :P