# Winows 7 CommandLine terminal output store to TXT file, but keep output show in terminal too

Tags: windows, command-line, output

I use the next code in my bat file

```
@echo off
myTerminalApp.exe >> output.txt
```

when I run the bat file, it runs in the terminal and my app works. It stores all output to the txt file as expected, but does not display the output in terminal.

So how can I make it save the output to the txt file and display that output in the terminal window as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file)

Comment: not work for me