# How to run powershell with a command containing quote?

Tags: powershell

I want to use the powershell command in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20854632/2704265)

However, my command contains quote itself, like below:

```
call mybatchfile "%~f1" "%~2"
```

How to invoke it from powershell? Double quotes them as below?

```
powershell "call mybatchfile "%~f1" "%~2" | tee test.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- The answer below assumes that you want to call a PowerShell command *from a batch file* (via `cmd.exe`), via the PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe`) - only in batch files do expressions such as `%~f1` and `%~2` work.
- (If you're calling *from PowerShell*, you can invoke a batch file directly, e.g. `& .\mybatchfile "foo" "bar" | tee text.txt`)

---

> `powershell "call mybatchfile "%~f1" "%~2" | tee test.txt"`

- PowerShell doesn't have a `call` keyword:

  - `&`, its [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), is loosely equivalent, but only strictly needed if the target command is specified as a *quoted* name or path and/or involves *variable references* (or expressions).
  - PowerShell doesn't allow you to execute batch files located in the *current* directory by *name only* - for security reasons, you must specify a *path* in that case, in the simplest case `.\mybatchfile`

    - For external programs (including batch files), invocation by name only (e.g. `mybatchfile`) works only if that program is in the system's path, i.e. located in one of the directories listed in the `$env:Path` environment variable.
- To use `"` chars. *embedded* in an overall `"..."` string, you must *escape* them, which - when calling the PowerShell *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)), means using `\"` (sic)

To put it all together:

```
powershell "& .\mybatchfile \"%~f1\" \"%~2\" | tee test.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

To make double-quotation marks appear in a string, enclose the entire string in single quotation marks.

```
call mybatchfile '"%~f1"' '"%~2"'
```

"You can enclose a string in single quotation marks ( ' ) or double quotation marks ( " ). Quotation marks are also used to create a here-string. A here-string is a single-quoted or double-quoted string in which quotation marks are interpreted literally. A here-string can span multiple lines."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3