# How to display the output text in the Windows command line while redirecting the output text in a file?

Tags: windows, cmd, tee

Currently I have a make file that will build my software using gnumake and currently I redirect my output text (like build logs, warnings, errors) in a file. But now I think it's very helpful to also display all the output text while building and while redirecting the output text in a file. Below is my current command,

```
gnumake -f Build.mak  1>Logs.txt 2>>&1
```

Is it possible to display the output text while redirecting the output text in a file?

Comment: Don't know about `dos`, but in unix land this is done by `tee`, i.e. `make | tee logfile`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I echo and send console output to a file in a bat script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a old post, but was never answered correctly. 
Here is one answer for other future viewers. 
You don't need `tee` to be able to log a file and show the text. There is another way.

This question was answered on StackOverflow. Here are the 2 links:

If you don't want to use `tee` check this: [When adding a TextLog to Echo in Command Line, Input wont show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071904/when-adding-a-textlog-to-echo-in-command-line-input-wont-show-up)

For `tee` you can see this: [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file?lq=1)

Just going to throw the answer here.

In dos yo can use this without using tee.

```
set LogFile=path\logfile.txt
set TempLog=path\temp
set logg=^> %TempLog%^&^& type %TempLog%^&^&type %TempLog%^>^>%LogFile%
```

If you need to create directory or/and logfile.txt do this.

```
if not exist "path" mkdir "path" >>nul
echo. 2>  %LogFile%  >nul
echo. 2>  %TempLog%  >nul
```

Now just use `echo` like this:

```
echo This will show me a text and logg  %logg%
```

Answer (score 2):

if you install cygwin (unix tools on ms windows), you can use the "tee" command:
gnumake -f Build.mak | tee Logs.txt

(this will save the output to Logs.txt and at the same time show the output to the console).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SOq:

- [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/dos-command-to-display-result-on-console-and-redirect-the-output-to-a-file)

Basically, you can use `tee` command e.g. from here:

- http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced version of [Avrumi Sherman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2828519/avrumi-sherman) with handling of `STDERR` *and* `STDOUT`:

```
D:\>dir ERROR 1>log.txt 2>&1 & type log.txt
 Datenträger in Laufwerk D: ist DATA
 Volumeseriennummer: 4653-A096

 Verzeichnis von D:\Projekte\UDG_TMP\build-deploy

 Datei nicht gefunden
```

So it displays the `STDTOUT` (first lines) *and* the `STDERR` (last line) on screen *and* the log-file.

For usage in a batch file just do it like [Avrumi Sherman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2828519/avrumi-sherman) did but use a *single* `&` in order to catch the *ERROR*-cases as well:

```
D:\>set logFile=log.txt
D:\>set tmpLog=tmp.txt
D:\>set logCmd=1^>%tmpLog% 2^>^&1 ^& type %tmpLog% ^& type %tmpLog%^>^>%logFile%
```

Now you can use the `logCmd` variable like a logCmd ;)

Note the ERROR messages of the first `dir` and the second `rmdir` are displayed on screen as well as appearing in the log-file:

```
D:\>echo START %logCmd%
START

D:\>dir DIRECTORY %logCmd%
 Datenträger in Laufwerk D: ist DATA
 Volumeseriennummer: 4653-A096

 Verzeichnis von D:\

Datei nicht gefunden

D:\>mkdir DIRECTORY %logCmd%

D:\>dir DIRECTORY %logCmd%
 Datenträger in Laufwerk D: ist DATA
 Volumeseriennummer: 4653-A096

 Verzeichnis von D:\DIRECTORY

26.08.2020  17:50    <DIR>          .
26.08.2020  17:50    <DIR>          ..
               0 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 68.391.989.248 Bytes frei

D:\>rmdir DIRECTORY %logCmd%

D:\>rmdir DIRECTORY %logCmd%
Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

D:\>echo STOP %logCmd%
STOP
```

At the end of your batch file you can/should delete `%tmpLog%`. Here the content of `%logFile%` using the example above:

```
START
 Datenträger in Laufwerk D: ist DATA
 Volumeseriennummer: 4653-A096

 Verzeichnis von D:\

Datei nicht gefunden
 Datenträger in Laufwerk D: ist DATA
 Volumeseriennummer: 4653-A096

 Verzeichnis von D:\DIRECTORY

26.08.2020  17:50    <DIR>          .
26.08.2020  17:50    <DIR>          ..
               0 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 68.391.989.248 Bytes frei
Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
STOP
```