# When adding a TextLog to Echo in Command Line, Input wont show up

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I know when we add the `>>` after `echo` the output works but in the command line itself it's hidden. I'd like to know if there is a way I can do both without duplicating my code. So it should show in the command line and the output file.

```
Echo ### Backing up Drivers >> %Drive%:\Backup\Backup-Log.txt
Ping 127.0.0.1  >nul
xcopy "%HOMEDRIVE%\drivers" /c /d /h /e /i /y "%Drive%:\Backup\Drivers"  >> %Drive%:\Backup\Backup-Log.txt

echo ### Backing up the Registry... >> %Drive%:\Backup\Backup-Log.txt
if not exist "%Drive%\Registry" mkdir "%Drive%:\Backup\Registry"
if exist "%Drive%\Registry\regbackup.reg" Echo "Replacing %Drive%:\Backup\Registry\regbackup.reg" >> %Drive%:\Backup\Backup-Log.txt
if exist "%Drive%\Registry\regbackup.reg" del "%Drive%:\Backup\Registry\regbackup.reg" >> %Drive%:\Backup\Backup-Log.txt
regedit /c /d /h /e /i /y  "%Drive%:\Backup\Registry\regbackup.reg" >> %Drive%:\Backup\Backup-Log.txt
```

Comment: Use a TEE filter that works in Windows NT line.  Swiss File Knife is one tool which has it.  `SFK - The Swiss File Knife File Tree Processor.`

Comment: Here's another thread with the same question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file

Comment: Thanks I guess i will delete this soon, since its a dubale. Thanks James and fox.

Comment: Sorry i cant comment over there since i need 50 rep so i am gonna comment here. i found this, but how do i use it? ECHO Print line to screen and log to file.  >_ && type _ && type _ >> logfile.txt what dose the _ && type _ && type _  mean?

Comment: Thats on old Post i think back in 2009. those answers don't work for me. i dont want to download a program since i am using this for other 100 computers. it might of work in xp but not in 7.

Comment: @AvrumiSherman: for explanation see my answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I echo and send console output to a file in a bat script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an explanation from an old answer of mine

for this purpose I use the following:

```
set LogFile=somepath\logfile.txt
set logg=^> _^&^& type _^&^&type _^>^>%LogFile%
echo this goes to screen AND file! %logg%
```

This is a bit tricky. So let's disassemble that line to four parts:

```
set logg=      ^> _          ^&^& type _           ^&^&type _^>^>%LogFile%
```

The Idea is to print the line to a temporary file (named "_") (second part) then type the contents of that file to screen (third part) then type it to the logfile (fourth part).

Put that all to a variable (first part), so you don't have to type that monsterstring to every line. (this is the reason why the ">" and "&" are escaped with "^")

So every time you use

```
echo whatever %logg%
```

it will appear on the screen AND write to %logfile%

---

You can find the complete answer here: [How do I make a log of all ECHO commands in a BATCH file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551379/how-do-i-make-a-log-of-all-echo-commands-in-a-batch-file/15553922#15553922)

NOTES:

one `&` is enough, so instead of `^&^&` write only `^&`

The disadvantage is: it generates Disk-IO every time, you use it.

Comment: I am getting access is denied Using windows 7. Thats what happened to me before, i guess i thute there was a problem with the script. Any clues on how to run this batch as administrator?

Comment: Wait let me play around with it. i got something but then it wont save it to log.

Comment: I got it I will post my answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: the "Access denied" problem propbably is: the temporary file (named `_`) will be put into the current directory, which you may not have wirte-permission. Workarounds: a) `cd /d %~dp0` at the beginning of the script b) name the tempfile with a path to a dir witch you have permissions for example: `%temp%\_` instead of `_`

Comment: If you'd like the temporary file to be automatically cleaned up, add `^&^& DEL _` to the end of the `logg` variable.

Comment: deleting the file `_` each time costs an additional disk access and so slows it down. If needed, delete it once at the end of the script.