# Redirecting windows system errors

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the equivalent of the following in a batch script:

```
net localgroup "Cool Usergroup"
```

This may succeed, or it may fail for various reasons including:

```
System error 1376 has occurred.

The specified local group does not exist.
```

or

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

The problem is I need to look for these error codes, but the output is not coming through standard out or standard error.  I've tried this:

```
net localgroup "Cool Usergroup" 2>&1 > %temp%\myGarbage.txt
```

But I still get the output splashed on the screen, not in the file.

To give a little more context, my original command is running in a for loop, and I'd like to get it working inside there, but there are additional problems with that.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ( 'net localgroup "Cool Usergroup" 2>&1') do echo out: %i
```

gives me:

```
2>&1 was unexpected at this time.
```

So, how do I process these system errors in a batch script using a for loop?  It doesn't seem the output goes through standard error or standard out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works on my system:

```
net localgroup "Cool Usergroup" > %temp%\myGarbage.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: +1 and accepted answer to you for figuring out that Windows is picky about ordering.  -1 to Microsoft for making it that way.

Comment: Though I'll also vote up anyone who can tell me how to do this in a for loop.  You didn't answer that part.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want to loop over using **for** statement. Content of () in **for** statement should represent a set, but I don't see how **net localgroup** can represent a set.

Comment: This explains a bit the [SO:redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4588136/463115), and why the order is important

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for just required some extra character escapes:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('net localgroup ^"Cool Usergroup^" 2^>^&1') do echo out: %i
```

That way I can parse for specific error messages in the loop.  Keeping the accepted answer with Kamyar though since he gave me the breakthrough I needed.