# output to log file and also to screen batch file

Tags: batch-file

I write a batch file.
does it possible to send the output to log file and also to screen??
my command is:
**sqlplus -S %USER_NAME%/%PASSWORD%@%TNS_NAME% OG.2ation.sql**
I want that the output of this command will be in the screen and also to log file.????

Comment: If you are on *nix then the `tee` command will do it. As in `sqlplus -S ... | tee mylog.log`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file) and of [Displaying and storing Windows Batch file output](http://superuser.com/questions/29295/displaying-and-storing-windows-batch-file-output).

Comment: Another duplicate - this one with a simple hybrid batch/JScript answer that provides a proper asynchronous tee functionality using purely native scripting: [Using a custom Tee command for .bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711839/1012053)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own tee program with batch.

Use it with `myProgram | tee.bat outfile.txt`

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "outfile=%~1"

(
  for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`find /N /V ""`) DO (
    set "line=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:*]=!"
    (echo(!line!) > con
    (echo(!line!)
    endlocal
  )
) > "%outfile%"
```

Comment: Nice, but unfortunately this script runs into problems if `myProgram` reads from `stdin`. For instance, if `myProgram` is a batch script with 3 lines: `@echo Hello`, `@pause` and `@echo world`, then nothing is displayed on the console until `myProgram` terminates...

Comment: Yes, it waits until the complete data is transfered, but in the case of the OP this seems to be OK

Comment: Wouldn't `myProgram >outfile.txt & type outfile.txt` work just as effectively as this batch script? It sure is a lot simpler.

Comment: @dbenham - Hmmm, perhaps you are right :-) But with tee.bat you could change the code of tee.bat to an async variation