# How to create a BATCH file to open an exe file and then insert values

Tags: batch-file

I have a `login.exe` file. If you run it, it will ask for an user name, and then a password for the username, like this:

1. ask for username:

   `Username: viktor`
2. if you pressed ENTER after the user name, ask for the password:

   `viktor@10.10.0.1's password:`

I want to create a BATCH file, and when I run this BATCH file, it will open the `login.exe` and paste the username I use, wait for the next step, and then paste my password. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: `sendkeys` in a batch+vbs script or `AutoIt` can help there, if Aacini's suggestion doesn't work with your exe.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the way `login.exe` read its input. If it follows the standard way, this method should work:

```
(
echo viktor
echo password
) | login.exe
```

If this not works, then there is no way to do so...

Answer (score 1):

for open your login.exe

```
start  PATH
```

example

```
START C:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE
```

if u want to put in automatic way your username and password i think is not possibile, because you need a comunication between the .exe and .batch file

i suggest to you to write your login.exe in batch.
so you cane have all in 1 file, when it works you can compile it in .exe format

Answer (score 1):

i'd try

```
set /p UName=Name?
set /p Pwd=Password? 

start Login.exe %UName% %Pwd%
```

while it might be neccessary to use `call` instead of `start` to get vars Extended

```
call Login.exe %UName% %Pwd%
```

or if you don't need the batch really, why not start the login.exe by a shortcut this way?

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /k set /p Uname=Name? && set /p PWD=Password? && call login.exe %Uname% %PWD%
```

and if your login.exe does not take the input with call, you could use this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719322/2167103) script for your purpose and call Login.exe instead of the example mycommand.exe in code.