# Display execution on console as well as write logs in a file

Tags: java, batch-file, logging, jar, console.log

Currently, I am using the following code to trigger a jar file and write the logs. It writes the logs in a file but doesn't show the execution on the console window.

```
>>"D:\Debug\logfile.log" java -jar Q3587.jar
```

Please, suggest what changes I can see the logs on console as well. I cannot use Log4j.

Comment: On Windows you could use Powershell `get-content logfile.log -Wait` a somewhat "tail -f" - equivalent. If you have git-bash or cygwin you can actually use tail -f

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10719322/1683264

Comment: you can run both command at the same time like this: `>>"logfile.log" java -jar Q3587.jar & get-content logfile.log -Wait`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a custom Tee command for .bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711839/using-a-custom-tee-command-for-bat-file)