# Redirecting command output to stdout and pipe in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe

Ok so I have this script where I redirect the output of an ant command to a pipe with findstr

```
ant xyz | findstr ...
```

but as you know the output of the command will not get displayed on the stdout. So is there a way that we can redirect the output to both the pipe and stdout without using files?

Comment: Not built into Windows that I'm aware of... you need the equivalent of a Unix program called `tee` (that forms a T-junction in a pipe) that will send its input both to stdout and further down the pipe. You should be able to find Windows versions kicking around the net (Cygwin, Git tools etc.)

Comment: check the `jtee` implementation of the tee command for windows - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10719322/388389

Comment: Just to add some more references [mtee](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/mtee/)
[Bill Stewart's Tee](http://www.westmesatech.com/sst.html)
[GnuWin32 Tee](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)