# Piping private key (variable) to a "for loop" to generate public key

Tags: batch-file, pipe, private-key, public-key, wireguard

I am trying to write a small batch script that will run on Windows systems and generate new WireGuard config files that are ready for deployment in a road warrior setup.

To do this I am saving the output of `wg genkey`, `wg pubkey` and `wg genpsk` to variables in the script.
Based on these variables it will then generate a new `client.conf`.

In `bash` this wouldn't be a problem.
`wg genkey | tee privatekey | wg pubkey > publickey`

In `batch` however I can't figure out a nice and clean way of piping the private key to the `wg pubkey` command without loosing the private key of the `wg genkey` command.

**Preferred Solution**
Public key generation not working.

```
REM generate private key --> WORKING
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%f in (`wg genkey`) do (set var_privatekey=%%f)

REM generate public key --> NOT WORKING
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%f in (`echo %var_privatekey% ^| wg pubkey`) do (set var_publickey=%%f)

REM generate preshared key --> WORKING
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%f in (`wg genpsk`) do (set var_presharedkey=%%f)
```

**Woraround**
Use tmp files. Though this is working I would prefer if the keys are not written to any files.

```
REM generate public key from var_privatekey
REM
echo %var_privatekey% | (wg pubkey) >publickey.tmp & <publickey.tmp (set /p var_publickey=)
del publickey.tmp
```

Comment: Why not pipe the result of the genkey directly to the pubkey?

Comment: @Gerhard - Based on his bash example, he wants to save the result of the genkey to a file, as well as sending it on to gen the pubkey.

Comment: PowerShell has a `Tee-Object` cmdlet; perhaps you should look at doing this in PowerShell instead of winbatch?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, OP states _" I would prefer if the keys are not written to any files."_

Comment: @Gerhard - I somehow missed that. In that case, `Tee-Object` is inappropriate, but it can still be done in PowerShell if the querent considers that an acceptable route.  One can assign the output of a command to a variable via `$foo = (desiredcommand)`, and then use `$foo` as input/parameters to other commands or the pipeline.

Comment: Sadly I am not familiar at all with powershell. Is there no way of doing this in batch?

Comment: Have you tried piping directly from one to the next? I do now have `wg` to test this for you.

Comment: Could you please give an example for this? I don't quite get what you mean by that.

Comment: for instance `wg genkey| wg pubkey`

Comment: ````for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%f in (wg genkey | wg pubkey) do (set var_publickey=%%f)````  
This will lose the private key and only save the public key.

Comment: Does this help you: [Using a custom Tee command for .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719322)?

Comment: This might even work. But is pretty overkill for just one command I think. Thanks anyway!