# MsgBox "" vs MsgBox() in VBScript

Tags: function, vbscript

I'm trying to write a VBScript and I'm using functions such as Randomize, and MsgBox. I'm curious as to what is the difference of using () and not using them. For example:

`Randomize` - This line works.

`Randomize()` - This line works also.

`MsgBox "Hello, World!"` - This works.

`MsgBox ("Hello, World!")` - This works as well.

The script will be running on multiple machines with different versions of Windows (at least [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP)). I'm wondering if I would be getting any compatibility/syntax issues in using these functions.

Answer (score 29):

A callable piece of code (routine) can be a *Sub* (called for a side effect/what it does) or a *Function* (called for its return value) or a mixture of both. As the documentation for MsgBox,

> Displays a message in a dialog box, waits for the user to click a
> button, and returns a value indicating which button the user clicked.
>
> MsgBox(prompt[, buttons][, title][, helpfile, context])

indicate, this routine is of the third kind.

The syntactical rules of VBScript are simple:

**Use parameter list () when calling a (routine as a) function**

If you want to display a message to the user and need to know the user's response:

```
Dim MyVar
MyVar = MsgBox ("Hello, World!", 65, "MsgBox Example")
   ' MyVar contains either 1 or 2, depending on which button is clicked.
```

**Don't use parameter list () when calling a (routine as a)** ***Sub***

If you want to display a message to the user and are not interested
in the response:

```
MsgBox "Hello, World!", 65, "MsgBox Example"
```

This beautiful simplicity is messed up by:

The design flaw of using () for parameter lists and to force call-by-value semantics

```
>> Sub S(n) : n = n + 1 : End Sub
>> n = 1
>> S n
>> WScript.Echo n
>> S (n)
>> WScript.Echo n
>>
2
2
```

S (n) does not mean "call S with n", but "call S with a copy of n's value".

Programmers seeing that

```
>> s = "value"
>> MsgBox(s)
```

'works' are in for a surprise when they try:

```
>> MsgBox(s, 65, "MsgBox Example")
>>
Error Number:       1044
Error Description:  Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub
```

The compiler's leniency with regard to empty () in a *Sub* call. The 'pure'

Sub Randomize (called for the side effect of setting the random seed) can be called by

```
Randomize()
```

although the () can neither mean "give me your return value) nor "pass
something by value". A bit more strictness here would force programmers to be aware of the difference in

```
Randomize n
```

and

```
Randomize (n)
```

The *Call* statement that allows parameter list () in *Sub* calls:

```
>> s = "value"
>> Call MsgBox(s, 65, "MsgBox Example")
```

which further encourage programmers to use () without thinking.

(Based on [What do you mean "cannot use parentheses?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx))

Comment: I would recommend using **vbOkCancel** instead of hard coding 65.  It's more readable.

Comment: 65 == **vbOkCancel + vbInformation** Constants are available here: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/constants/msgbox_args.php

Comment: I understand how to use this, but I'd like to get more clarity. Is MsgBox a function or a Sub or a Hybrid of some kind?

Answer (score 10):

To my knowledge, these are the rules for calling subroutines and functions in VBScript:

- When calling a subroutine or a function where you discard the return value, don't use parentheses
- When calling a function where you assign or use the return value, enclose the arguments in parentheses
- When calling a subroutine using the `Call` keyword, enclose the arguments in parentheses

Since you probably won’t be using the `Call` keyword, you only need to learn the rule that **if you call a function and want to assign or use the return value you need to enclose the arguments in parentheses. Otherwise, don't use parentheses.**

Here are some examples:

- `WScript.Echo 1, "two", 3.3` - calling a subroutine
- `WScript.Echo(1, "two", 3.3)` - syntax error
- `Call WScript.Echo(1, "two", 3.3)` - keyword `Call` requires parentheses
- `MsgBox "Error"` - calling a function "like" a subroutine
- `result = MsgBox("Continue?", 4)` - calling a function where the return value is used
- `WScript.Echo (1 + 2)*3, ("two"), (((3.3)))` - calling a subroutine where the arguments are computed by expressions involving parentheses (note that if you surround a variable by parentheses in an argument list it changes the behavior from call by reference to call by value)
- `WScript.Echo(1)` - apparently this is a subroutine call using parentheses, but in reality, the argument is simply the expression `(1)`, and that is what tends to confuse people that are used to other programming languages where you have to specify parentheses when calling subroutines
- I'm not sure how to interpret your example, `Randomize()`. `Randomize` is a subroutine that accepts a single optional argument, but even if the subroutine didn't have any arguments, it is acceptable to call it with an empty pair of parentheses. It seems that the VBScript parser has a special rule for an empty argument list. However, my advice is to avoid this special construct and simply call any subroutine without using parentheses.

I'm quite sure that these syntactic rules applies across different versions of operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

You are just using a single parameter inside the function, hence it is working fine in both the cases, like follows:

```
MsgBox "Hello, World!"
MsgBox ("Hello, World!")
```

But when you'll use more than one parameter, in VBScript a method with parentheses will throw an error and without parentheses will work fine like:

```
MsgBox "Hello, World!", vbExclamation
```

The above code will run smoothly, but

```
MsgBox ("Hello, World!", vbExclamation)
```

will throw an error.

Try this!! :-)

Comment: please rectify your last example

Comment: Thanks @Ekkehard.Horner!! I had described it in a simple manner( or you may say in a lay man's language). What you want me to modify in it. Please elaborate. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: your last example is just a copy of the working one, so it won't throw an error.

Comment: Hey Thanks @Ekkehard.Horner for warning me. I got your point and rectified my answer. I forgot to put parenthesis in my last example. Thank you so much!!

Comment: just FYI, MsgBox with parentheses and multiple variables will work, i.e. if you are assigning it to a value

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between subroutines and functions in VBA... Generally (as far as I know), subroutines do not return anything and the surrounding parentheses are optional. For functions, you need to write the parentheses.

As for your example, MsgBox is not a function but a subroutine and therefore the parentheses are optional in that case. One exception with functions is, when you do not assign the returned value, or when the function does not consume a parameter, you can leave away the parentheses too.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls) goes into a bit more detail, but basically you should be on the save side, when you provide parentheses for functions and leave them away for subroutines.

Comment: MsgBox is just one example for a routine that can be used as a Sub or a Function; parameter list () are *forbidden* in Sub calls; 'consume' is a misleading term when applied to parameter passing semantics.

Comment: Forbidden, unless you use the `Call` keyword.