# Can't Use Parentheses When Calling a Sub - VBScript

Tags: vbscript, parentheses

I'm writing this code in VBScript, which I haven't used before in my life.

I wrote this: Replace (strContent, st, arr (k,i), 1)

And it gives me a "Can't Use Parentheses When Calling a Sub" problem.
Can anyone please help?

I've tried searching online but nothing helped.

Thank you!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13622374/603855

Comment: Saw that, didn't quite understand what the solution is...

Comment: This is so popular issue for new in VBScript, `Replace` is Function that return result you s'd assign to variable, like `strResult=Replace(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to Panayot Karabakalov.

We tried using a `Call` and doing it without parentheses:

```
Replace strContent, st, arr (k,i), 1
```

But nothing worked. The solution eventually was:

```
strContent = Replace (strContent, st, arr (k,i), 1)
```

Thank you everyone for the quick and helpful responses! You guys never let us down.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, when you use a procedure or function like this:

```
Foobar arg1, arg2, arg3
```

you must not use parentheses around the argument list. When you use the `Call` keyword or use the return value of a function in an assignment or a condition, then you must use parentheses around the argument list, e.g.:

```
Call Foobar(arg1, arg2, arg3)

result = Foobar(arg1, arg2, arg3)

If Foobar(arg1, arg2, arg3) Then
  ...
End If
```

Comment: We tried with a "Call" and without parentheses as in your first example and it didn't work. The solution for us was using the return value.