# VBScript Object Required When Trying to set DateTime

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am new to VBScript and can't figure out why I'm getting an `Object Required` error with my code. It's very simple right now, I've just begun it:

```
<%
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim dateandtime
On Error Resume Next
set dateandtime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
If Err <> 0 Then
  ' File operation(s) failed, handle the error
  response.write(Err.Description)
End If
%>
```

Why am I not able to set the DateTime? I've set the FileSystemObject for use later in the code FYI. I'm just putting it all in here so you see exactly what I have. I figure it's a simple syntax thing but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Object required" when using Set in an assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633643/object-required-when-using-set-in-an-assignment)

Comment: Same issue use of `Set` on data types that are not objects (in VBScript). Also use of .Net syntax  `DateTime.Now.ToString()` should be `Now()` for Classic ASP equivalent or a custom date format. See [Answer to Classic ASP - Format current date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first mistake is to use `Set` when assigning a non-object to a variable. The last entry in the 'Related' list [“Object required” when using Set in an assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23633643/603855) deals with it.

```
>> Set dt = "a string"
>>
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required [because Set wants an object to assign]
```

No Set, no problem:

```
>> dt = "a string"
>> WScript.Echo dt
>>
a string
```

Removing the `Set` will reveal the next problem: Unless you defined a suitable class and an instance named 'DateTime' of your own, `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")` will fail with the same error 424.

```
>> dt = Nix.Now.ToString("")
>>
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required [to use its .Now member]
```

Do a search here for ways to format a date in VBScript. (First hit for "[vbscript] format date": [date format in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9641000/603855))

The () in the .Write call should be removed; they are **not** parameter list (), but 'pass me per value' (). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17948642/603855) and follow the link to Eric Lippert's article.

Comment: The OP is mixing .Net syntax and Classic ASP syntax hence the `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")`.

Comment: I maybe bias but personally this is a better example of [Custom date formatting in Classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart, this link is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. Ekkehard's answer definitely shed light on a lot for me though as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about crear your code and just do this?

```
<%
    dateandtime = now()

    response.write dateandtime
%>
```

To use `set`you need a `Object`.