# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' : object required

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Hi i have an ASP page that call function with 2 parameters

when i call the function from the asp page i am getting this error

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 
>   Object required: 'AllPerInfo4xfm(...)'

my code is

```
set GetAllInv = new GetFunction
set MyOrsk = GetAllInv.AllPerInfo4xfm(ssgr,nat)
```

my function is

```
Public Function AllPerInfo4xfm(ssgr,nat) 
   dim sdir,sdir2,ssec,tlen,ssec2
   tlen=len(ssgr)      
   sql ="Select * from Personal"
   myors2.Open SQl,oConn,1,1
   set Allperinfo4xf = myors2
end function
```

did i miss something 
please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `AllPerInfo4xfm()` does **not** return an object, loose the [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) in

```
set MyOrsk = GetAllInv.AllPerInfo4xfm(ssgr,nat)
```

=>

```
MyOrsk = GetAllInv.AllPerInfo4xfm(ssgr,nat)
```

**Update wrt comment:**

If `AllPerInfo4xfm()` should return a recordset, make sure the function contains a line

```
Set AllPerInfo4xfm = objRecordset
```

(replace objRecordset with your variable name; now, of course, the `Set` in the assignment to MyOrsk is needed)

**Update wrt OT's revision:**

Given the revised code, both `GetAllInv` and `myors2` should be checked. Are they valid objects when the line is executed?

cf. [food for thought](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647118/603855)

Comment: i am getting another error Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 
Object required: '' 

cuz the function should return a record set