# VBS won't allow programming

Tags: vbscript

I was doing some programming and I get an error message when I try and run it. my code:

```
MsgBox ("hi")
sleep (2)
MsgBox ("you ok" vbYesNo, "how are you?")

Select Case result
    Case vbYes,
        MsgBox ("that's good!")
    Case vbNo, MsgBox ("sorry to hear that.")
End Select
```

> Line: 3
>   Char: 18
>   Error: Expected ')' Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error.

Comment: Try `msgbox ("you ok", vbyesno, "how are you?")`

Comment: Once you fix that you'll also need to remove the trailing `,` on the end of the `Case` variables or you'll get `Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Syntax error`, also your `MsgBox()` function calls will either need a return value to use brackets or be prefixed with `Call Msgbox(...)`, not the mention your `Sleep()` as well plus it's only sleeping for `0.002` seconds *(`Sleep` is in milliseconds not seconds)*.

Comment: It would be nice if you'll carefully read docs about syntax of VBScript and the functions/statements you're trying to use https://ss64.com/vb/syntax.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is as the error says you have compilation issues but looking at the rest of the example code you also have other issues waiting to be corrected.

1. Missing argument syntax in `MsgBox()` Function:

   > Line: 3
   >
   > Char: 18
   >
   > Error: Expected ')' Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error.

   is because the Function `MsgBox()` expects arguments separated by a comma but the argument separator after `"you ok"` is missing causing the compiler to throw the exception.
2. Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub:

   When calling a procedure that doesn't return a value using brackets around multiple arguments passed to the procedure will cause;

   > Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub

   There is a caveat to this which is if it's just one argument it will not fail to compile, but this isn't because it accepts one argument but because it sees the brackets as part of the argument not part of the procedure *(Eric Lippert discusses this at length in [his blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/))*;

   ```vb
   MsgBox("Hi") 'Will work
   ```

   This is equivalent to writing;

   ```vb
   Call MsgBox(("Hi")) 'Note the extra brackets
   ```

   This can be a little confusing so when it comes to multiple arguments you might think this is ok;

   ```vb
   MsgBox("you ok", vbyesno, "how are you?") 'This will error
   ```

   But as the brackets now denote the argument parentheses it becomes invalid and throws a compilation error. To avoid this there are three things you can do;

   1. Remove the parentheses

      ```vb
       MsgBox "you ok", vbyesno, "how are you?"
      ```
   2. Return a value (if the procedure can return a value)

      ```vb
       result = MsgBox("you ok", vbYesNo, "how are you?")
      ```

      As you check the value of `result` on the next line this would be the correct option as it `result` will contain the outcome of clicking either `vbYes` or `vbNo` in the `MsgBox()` function.
   3. Use the `Call` statement to prefix the procedure call

      ```vb
       Call MsgBox("you ok", vbYesNo, "how are you?")
      ```
3. Syntax Error:

   > Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Syntax error

   This comes down to trailing commas after the `Case` arguments, just remove the commas and the code will compile.

   ```vb
   Select Case result
   Case vbYes
     Call MsgBox("that's good!")
   Case vbNo
     Call MsgBox("sorry to hear that.")
   End Select
   ```
4. The `Sleep` duration:

   The `Sleep()` function expects a value expressed in milliseconds not seconds, at the moment the example code is waiting for 0.002 seconds. To wait for 2 seconds *(which I'm assuming was the intention)* use;

   ```vb
   Call Sleep(2000)
   ```

---

#### Useful links

- [Answer to Can't Use Parentheses When Calling a Sub - VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17948642/692942)