# How to get usernames with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to move a .vbs file with a .movefile line, and I want to give the .vbs file to my friends, but in order for it to work I would have to know what their usernames are.

What would I use to make the .vbs file know their usernames. Example: "C:\users\username\desktop"

Answer (score 36):

To get the username of the person currently logged in:

```
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
```

Answer (score 5):

In VBScript you can get the path to the current user's desktop folder via the [`SpecialFolders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) collection:

```
WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")
```

That would store the username in the string "strName', so it would work like this:

```
x = messagebox("Hello ") + strName, 1, strName)
```

Or in your case:

```
x = messagebox("C:\Users\" + strName + "\Desktop\name", 1, "User name in C:\ directory below"
```

Comment: Is this a troll answer? And/or generated by a bot? Not actually tested? The result is likely syntax errors (can somebody confirm? Or otherwise). E.g., the parentheses are not balanced at all.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code:

```vb
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
User = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )
WScript.Echo "User: " & strUserName
```

Comment: Is it not covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43198013/692942), other than `WScript.Echo` to output the variable what extra value does this offer? You could have just as easily amended the existing answer to include this extra line.

Comment: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620748/msgbox-vs-msgbox-in-vbscript/59669761#59669761) was completely bogus, so the confidence is not high. Though the referenced answer to this question could also be bogus (more or less random code that does not compile?).