# How do I make a TTS bot speak out the computer username?

Tags: vbscript, basic

I'm trying to make a VBS script that can say your username on your computer by using TTS.

```
Dim ttsbot
set sapi = wscript.createobject("SAPI.Spvoice")
Sapi.speak "*username here*"
```

Can someone help me on how to get the user's name and assign it as a variable, so it can be pronounced from the TTS bot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As asked... Speak UserName:

```
Set Sapi = WScript.CreateObject("SAPI.Spvoice")
Set oWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
UserName = oWSH.RegRead("HKCU\Volatile Environment\UserName")
Sapi.Speak UserName
```

Alternative... Speak DisplayName:

```
Set Sapi = WScript.CreateObject("SAPI.Spvoice")
Set oWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
LoggedOnDisplayName = oWSH.RegRead("HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\1\LoggedOnDisplayName")
Sapi.Speak LoggedOnDisplayName
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [How to get username with vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276361/how-to-get-username-with-vbs/22277277). You can write like this code :

```
UserName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")
createobject("SAPI.Spvoice").Speak UserName
```

---

Or like this example too :

```
UserName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
createobject("SAPI.Spvoice").Speak UserName
```