# How can i print output of a command to a file in Batch Script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to call a command in batch file using "call" method and whatever is the output of that command, I want to write in a file.
I went through from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script) but cannot find the answer.

I am using this command

```
call %confPath% GetIniString %datFile% Keyname name >%newFile% >&1
```

but it creates a empty file always. How can i write the output of above command in the file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm fairly sure the command line as written doesn't work at all, as `>%newFile% >&1`is illegal. you meant to write `>%newFile% 2>&1`.

Comment: @ths i haven't tried this combination and it worked. Thanks ths!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>%newFile%` redirects the standard output to a file. in `>&1`, the `1` stands for standard output, and if no stream is specified, standard output is the default, so `>&1` redirects on itself, although it was already redirected with the first command. So, this is illegal and shouldn't produce a file at all. In my tests, this just aborts with an errormessage.

The usual idiom `2>&1`, OTOH, redirects stream 2, which is standard ERROR, to standard output, which ensures that both output and error messages end up in the file.