# Printing mongodump or mongorestore command output to a log file

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I am using this command to save output to a file.

```
mongorestore --host %computerName%:%_portnumber% -u Admin -p user --oplogReplay %_sourceFolder% >> D:\Data\admin\abc.log
```

This creates an empty file and all the output is listed on the command prompt.

Is there a way to get the output to a file? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, I use below this

mongodump.exe /d test /o C:\Work 2> C:\temp\testdump.log

Actually, stream2 is STDERR but it works for MongoDB.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script)