# Handle Windows command prompt input from keyboard and display output and also redirecting it to a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, stdin, tee

Though I can find few relevant questions such as *[Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file)* and *[How do I echo and send console output to a file in a bat script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script)*, I could not fix my problem. I am working on Windows XP and running a few scripts using a batch file which uses STDIN and STDOUT handles.

Basically, I want to save the log file of command prompt. This is possible with "echo >> log.txt" in a batch file. However, this is not saving the outputs generated as a result of the script file. So I tried at the cmd prompt itself as D:>file.bat >"dir_path/log.txt". Again, this command saves the STDOUT to log.txt at the specified location. Since I need to get a few user inputs i.e. to use the STDIN handle, how do I achieve this in addition to saving the outputs of command prompts in separate file too?

Comment: I've used this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-mouse-hook-in-c/) to create [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/mouseSniffer.bat) .You can use it as a reference and check the [low level keyboard hook](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/) to create key logger.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

```
    @echo off
    set /p answ1=Get user input1
    set /p answ2=Get User input2
    echo %answ1% and %answ2%>>log.txt
    notepad log.txt
    set /p "var=<log.txt"
    type log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you redirect your .bat file to a file, you can output to the screen with `>con`.

Execute the following script with `test.bat >test.out`. It will prompt you for an input on the screen.

```
timeout -t 2
>con set /p "var1=Prompt1: "
ipconfig
>con set /p "var2=Prompt2: "
echo %var1% %var2%
>con echo %var1% %var2%
exit /b
```