# command prompt auto write to log file

Tags: cmd, io-redirection

I have a batch file named `very_good02.bat`. When I run it, it will show some progress info in command prompt.

I wish to auto write a log file that consists of all this progress information with the file name I keyed (which is `very_good02`).

I tried to ran it like this : `very_good02.bat > very_good02log.txt` the process is running in background where I can't see them in command prompt.

Comment: I think your questions is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script).

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I am not quite understand about the answer on that particular post. 
I was thinking that if I ran the bat file. (very_good02.bat) with added some line to it inside the bat, it will auto generate a text file copy all the process information and save into a txt file name very_good02.txt.

Sorry if I didn't explain it clearly.

Comment: erm, perhaps something like 
select all,
save as,
"same file name".txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I echo and send console output to a file in a bat script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are seeking is a way to "tee" the pipeline to both the console and a log file.

The `tee` command has been in UNIX/Linux for a long time. No such thing in Windows cmd.exe. But, PowerShell does have `Tee-Object`. At a PowerShell command prompt, use `help Tee-Object -full` for more information.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile "& .\very_good02.bat | Tee-Object -FilePath 'C:\src\t\very_good02.log'"
```

Naturally, this is easier if your whole script is in PowerShell and not in cmd script language. You don't have to use PowerShell, but that is the clearly stated direction from Microsoft.

I am reminded that this can, actually, be done in a cmd .bat file script. Not easily, but it can be done. https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=32615#p32615 If anyone can do it in a .bat file script, Mr. Benham can.